# Get children of element using javascript

Tags: javascript, image

how can i use Javascript, not jQuery, to get all images inside of a certain element. I need to be getting them by tag as well.

Also im looking for that images that get effected by

```
#container img
```

not

```
#container > img
```

Thanks, Luke :).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children

Comment: [`Element.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) or [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try this:

```
var cont = document.getElementById("container");
var all_img = cont.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

Comment: `getElement*s*ByTagName`

Comment: I believe that is what he asked for

Answer (score 3):

using only Javascript, then the function `querySelecterAll` is the right function to go with.

For only direct children:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#container > img');
$("#length").text(elements.length);
```

For all children:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#container img');
$("#length").text(elements.length);
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/YfPQv/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.getElementById("#container").children;`

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
parent.getElementsByTagName('img')
```